# Which squares succeed a factorial?

Tags: nt.number-theory

One notices that $5^2=4!+1$, $11^2=5!+1$, and $71^2=7!+1$. Are there others?

Comment: This is known as Brocard's problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem and is unsolved still

Comment: @Aleks: If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.